# Why can't Software Recommendations SE users spell "management"?

Tags: discussion

As of a few minutes ago, there were over 10 questions/answers with the word "management" spelled incorrectly.

As an example of a common misspelling, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=managment

I tend not to fix trivial spelling errors in posts more than a few hours old, because it messes up the order.  So I only fixed the one just posted a few minutes ago.

But there's a bigger issue at play: ***Does this represent a subconscious revolt against management?***

Comment: Alert the media :)

Comment: -> http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell-checker :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt LOL.  Good link.  I think almost all technology these days includes spell checkers.  It's like people just ignore them and click "post" without taking a moment to fix it.  Maybe spelling makes no difference these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is a continuation of a rebellion that began a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away... *(cue John Williams)*